# Game Level Unlocking Logic Java

Tags: java, beginner, android

I am making a quiz game and every time you complete a stage, the next stage will be unlocked.

**The Problem:**
When I am at Stage 3 and finish it, Stage 4 is unlocked. But when I feel like I want to play stage 1 again and finish it, the unlocked stage reverts to only Stage 2.

**The Code:**

```java
protected void stageCompleted(){



        //If the stage is completed unlock the next stage
        if(10-correctAnswers<=mistakesAllowed){
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("saves",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("completeStages", stageNumber+1);
            editor.commit();

        }
```

**And here is my Stages List.java file:**

```java
public class StagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Stage> stageList=new ArrayList<Stage>();
    Button backBtn;
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener onPrefsChangeListener;

    private ListView stagesListView;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stages);

       sharedPref = StagesActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("saves",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        stagesListView=findViewById(R.id.stages_list_view);
        backBtn=findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        initListView();


        onPrefsChangeListener=new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
                initListView();
            }
        };

        sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onPrefsChangeListener);



    }

    public void initListView(){
        JSONTools.readFileWithStages(StagesActivity.this,stageList);
        int completeStages=sharedPref.getInt("completeStages",0);
        Log.d("COMPLETED","COM:"+completeStages);
        for(int i=0;i<stageList.size();i++){
            if(completeStages>=i)
            stageList.get(i).setEnabled(true);
        }

        StagesListAdapter adapter = new StagesListAdapter(StagesActivity.this,stageList);


        stagesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sharedPref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onPrefsChangeListener);
    }
}
```

**Stages List after Completing Stage 1 again:**
[image: Stage List After Completing Stage 1 Again]

**Even if I completed Stage 3 and unlocked Stage 4:**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the code review website where we review code that is working as expected and provide suggestions on how that code might be improved. Code that is not working as expected is considered off-topic for this website. Unfortunately we can't help debug the program, you might get help from the stackoverflow.com website, but please look at their guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help first to see if the question meets the requirements. You can also search their previous questions to see if the question has already been answered.